# web scraping: how to process RSS feed

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am working on a project that requires retrieving craigslist listings and saving them into a structured table format. Although no API is available, the URL `http://boston.craigslist.org/search/hhh?format=rss&query=apartments` returns some of what I need. What is the best way of reading the contents from that webpage and saving it into a table with a title, link, and description column? I tried the code below but it returned an error message.

```
library(rvest)
url <- "http://boston.craigslist.org/search/hhh?format=rss&query=apartments"
read_html(url)

#error msg
Error in UseMethod("read_xml") : 
  no applicable method for 'read_xml' applied to an object of class "function"
```

Thanks

Comment: try renaming `url` to `urls`. `url` is also a function (see `?url`). Somehow this confuses __R__

Comment: You're probably going to get XML back, not HTML, FYI.

Comment: Perhaps just use the [`feedeR package`](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/feedeR/index.html)?